# Using Debug.WriteLine to write to Output window (VS2012)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

I've used a good part of yesterday reading through all the related posts on SO and other online forums to find a solution to this seemingly very straightforward problem that is driving me nuts.

For some reason, I just cannot seem to be able to print anything to the Output window of my Visual Studio 2012 (Ultimate). A quick run-down of what I tried:

- Put 'Solution Configurations' in debug mode
- Put 'Show output from' in debug mode
- Right-click Output window to open a dialog and make sure 'Program Output' is checked. In my case, I have everything checked
- Tools | Options | Debugging -> 'Redirect all Output Window text to the Immediate Window' is UNchecked
- Tools | Import and Export Settings -> Reset all settings (just in case I tweaked something unintentionally)

I've tried all of the above and some more to no avail. I mean, I've spent a fair share of my time using a number of widely used IDEs but never had this much difficulty with simply trying to print something in the Output window.

Lastly, it probably doesn't add any value to this post but here's my stupid-simple code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace DataProc.classes
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("I hate you, silly VS!!!");
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: (Adding web.config)

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Is "Define TRACE constant" checked under the project's build properties?

Comment: @yenta Yes, I have both 'TRACE constant' and 'DEBUG constant' checked

Comment: Is this a new project? Anything weird in the app.config if one exists?

Comment: Are there any VS addons installed?

Comment: @yenta I have no 'app.config'. However, I do have web.config and I added it to my OP

Comment: @sasha No, this is a out-of-the-box installation with no add-on

Comment: This a web application or a console application? Can you hit a break point on the Debug.WriteLine?

Comment: If this is a web application, as implied by the web.config, then Main isn't the entry point. Global asax is the start up class (or closest thing to it). If this is a console app, or winforms app, then the relevant config file is app.config.

Comment: @Matt This is a web app. I did put a break point on the Debug line but there's still no output.

Comment: Is it the only project in the solution and is it configured to build when the solution builds? Are you manually attaching to it or hitting F5?

Comment: @BinaryCat does it hit the breakpoint when you run it?

Comment: @Klors Yes, it is the only project in the solution. I hit F5 to build.

Comment: @yenta Yes, it hits the breakpoint when I run it

Comment: You could try ctrl + shift + P and find its application pool or dev environment manually in the list and attach that way...

Comment: @Matt To your second point, that is something I haven't thought of. Maybe I should try creating a Global asax file just to ensure there's an entry point?

Comment: What is the "Output type" set to under project properties? Are you targeting 4.5 or 4.5 (client profile) ?

Comment: @yenta Output type is currently set to 'class library'. Target framework is .NET Framework 4.5

Comment: Try switching to "Console Application".

Comment: @yenta Just tried it, no luck :(

Comment: Can you try creating a new console application to see if this is system wide?

Comment: `Put 'Solution Configurations' in debug mode` do you mean that if you right-click the solution and choose "configuration manager" that all of your entries are in Configuration of Debug and Platform of Any CPU and all ticked to build? In your project properties > build > advanced > debug info, is it set to full?

Comment: @Klors "Yes" to all your questions :) 
yenta - I should give it a try shortly

Comment: @BinaryCat well that is very strange, the only possible thing I can think of is that you've set your Output window's text colour to the same as the background colour :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset VS2012 settings to default.
You can do it from command line as shown here: [Reset VS2102 Settings](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fms241273.aspx&ei=uF3WU9DkA6LJsQSrp4GoAQ&usg=AFQjCNG0CR8bisb5gsRARsndNa5ESwyRgA&sig2=FHjc7YGvL3b1mOJShBP3UA)

Comment: How is this different from resetting it using the GUI menu as I mentioned in my original post? (fifth bullet) Anyway, I tried the command line method but there's no luck.

Comment: It shouldn't be different, but my recent experience showed that devenv acts differently between the GUI mode and the command line while building setup projects...